# Event system - capture copy - paste event for keyword

Tags: 2013-sp1, event-system

I have a requirement in which I need to check:

> if keyword is created with copy-paste then I need to remove the
>   related keywords from the destination (new) keyword and if keyword is moved using
>   cut-paste then I need to keep the related keyword.

Can you please suggest how can I achieve this using Event system?

Comment: No event will happen server side for a copy-paste or cut-paste. Your only chance will be to implement something client side, such as a GUI Extension.

Comment: There will certainly be an event for the actual paste -- which is clearly the right moment to actually apply a change. It doesn't matter if the user selects Cut or Copy and then never selects Paste.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do this by subscribing to initiated phase of the copy event of a Keyword and removing the related Keywords.

For example:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Keyword, CopyEventArgs> (HandlerForKeywordCopyInitiated, EventPhases.Initiated);
```

Cutting and pasting is really just a save event with a new parent item. But since you wish to keep the related Keywords in that case anyway, you don't have to do anything for that scenario.

Comment: The problem with copy event is you don't get destination object so I can't do anything with copy event as per my understanding, let me know if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The general `RepositoryLocalObject.Copy` API (with associated `CopyEventArgs`) is intended to copy Repository Local Objects in general (incl. Keywords) within an Organizational Item or to another Organizational Item.

However, the Organizational Item of a Keyword is always a Category; a Taxonomy of Keywords looks like a containment tree in the GUI but is technically speaking just a tree representation of a Directed Acyclic Graph formed by Parent-Child associations between Keywords.

For example: if you have the following Taxonomy:

```
 Location (Category)
  USA (Keyword)
    Orlando (Keyword)
```

Then the Organizational Item (`Keyword.OrganizationalItem`) of both Keywords is the Category "Location"; the fact that Keyword "Orlando" is under "USA" in the taxonomy tree representation is because Keyword "Orlando" has Keyword "USA" as a Parent Keyword (`Keyword.ParentKeywords`).

Long story short: the general Copy API can copy a Keyword to another Category, but not to another location in a taxonomy of Keywords.
However, there is another API for that purpose: `Keyword.CopyToKeyword` (with associated `CopyToKeywordEventArgs`).

Likewise, for moving a Keyword to another location in a Taxonomy, there is a separate `Keyword.MoveToKeyword` API (with associated `MoveToKeywordEventArgs`)